# Trying to slightly alter logistic GLM - Link function seems unstable

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, link-function

So the data I have is whether a subject has performed a test correctly, or incorrectly. They have to match choose which of a pair of stimuli matches one they have memorized, and this gets harder and harder to figure out (represented by the "angle" parameter approaching zero) and at that point they get the test right 50% of the time.

So when "angle" is larger, they get the test right 100% of the time (so "correct" = 1, with no variance), but as "angle" approaches 0, "correct" is either 1 or 0, with a mean of 0.5, and a variance of 0.25. As "angle" changes, the subjects responding moves from getting the answer correct, to getting it right 50/50. Each subject is only tested at a given angle once.

I then give the subjects a intervention which I believe will make them worse at this task, hence shifting this curve to the right.

---

Small Edit: The above is what I want to know: Has the intervention made the subjects better or worse at the task. Because of ethical and financial reasons, each subject will experience the stimulus only once. Perhaps a mixed-effect model would be better. But right now I'm binning the data from all the subjects together. Ultimately, I'm not sure that is a huge sin, because this is not a within subjects experiments: some subjects get the intervention, and some do not.

---

This data is also like a logistic regression, but no matter how small "angle" becomes, the data will never become all zeros. Hence, I believe I need to run a binomial regression with a custom link function.

The curve should take on the form of:

```
y = 0.5 + (0.5 * exp(Beta*X) ) /( exp(Beta*X) + 1 )
```

The inverse of this (i.e. the link function) is then

```
log( (1-2*y)/(2*y-2) )
```

The deriviate of the inverse link function with respect to eta is

```
 0.5*exp(Beta*X) /( ( exp(Beta*X) + 1 ) * ( exp(Beta*X) + 1  ) )
```

So I have written my custom link function as

```
bills <- function() {
  ## link
  linkfun <- function(y) { 
    log( (1-2*y)/(2*y-2) )
  }

  ## inverse link
  linkinv <- function(eta) {
    tmp = exp(eta)
    0.5 + (0.5 * tmp) /( tmp + 1 ) 
  }

  ## derivative of invlink wrt eta
  mu.eta <- function(eta) {
    tmp = exp(eta)
    0.5*tmp /( ( tmp + 1 ) * ( tmp + 1  ) )
  }

  valideta <- function(eta) TRUE
  link <- "bills"
  structure(list(linkfun = linkfun, linkinv = linkinv,
                 mu.eta = mu.eta, valideta = valideta, 
                 name = link),  class = "link-glm")
}
vv <- bills()
```

In order to test that this function behaves, I have written the following script to make data like my real data:

```
n_reps = 10
differences = c(5,10,15,20)

output <- matrix(nrow = n_reps, ncol = length(differences))

d <- 1

for(dif in differences) {
  for(n in 1:n_reps) {
    sample_size <- 5
    dat_c <-data.frame(angle = rep(seq(0, 90, by=10), times = sample_size), treated = rep(0, times=sample_size*10))
    dat_d <-data.frame(angle = rep(seq(0, 90, by=10), times = sample_size), treated = rep(1, times=sample_size*10))

    my_sigmoid <- function(x, v50) {
      return( 0.5+(1-0.5)/(1+exp((v50-x)/5)) ) 
    }

    control_v50 = 45
    drug_v50 = control_v50 + dif
    dat_c$p <- my_sigmoid(dat_c$angle, control_v50)
    dat_d$p <- my_sigmoid(dat_d$angle, drug_v50)


    dat_c$correct <- as.integer(runif(nrow(dat_c))<dat_c$p)
    dat_d$correct <- as.integer(runif(nrow(dat_d))<dat_d$p)

    dat = merge(dat_c, dat_d, all=TRUE)

    mdl_simp <- glm(correct ~ angle, family = binomial(link=vv), data = dat, start=c(-3,.1))
    mdl_full <- glm(correct ~ angle + treated, family = binomial(link=vv), data = dat, start=c(-3,.1, .5))

    a <- anova(mdl_simp, mdl_full, test="Chisq")

    p <- a$"Pr(>Chi)"[2]
    if ( is.na(p) ) {
      p <- 1
    }

    output[n, d] <- p
  }
  d <- d+1
}
```

However, when I run that script, I get constant errors like:

```
step size truncated: out of bounds
glm.fit: algorithm stopped at boundary value
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
Error: inner loop 1; cannot correct step size
```

I have double and triple checked my math, but I can't see any problem. The link function passes the typical suggested tests i.e. that running linkinv(linkinv(x)) returns x, and that mu.eta returns values that match a numerical calculation of the gradient of linkfunction.

But perhaps I am doing something else wrong? Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just model what you call angle with a non-negative distribution, like a gamma GLM, or beta regression? I would go with the latter, although I can't tell from your question whether angle is in $[0, 1]$ or $[0, \infty)$... Alternatively, if this 'angle' is hard to model, it might be easier to just model the ratio $\text{correct}:\text{incorrect}$. Can you elaborate why you want to model your data as you propose?

Comment: @FransRodenburg angle is in degrees. It's [0, 90]. But I don't understand that rest of your statement. Angle isn't hard to model. It's set by the experimenter. What I'm trying to model is how angle alters the probability of the subject getting the answer correct.

Why don't I just look at the ratio? Well because I generally try to avoid anything like that. I'm not actually sure what the correct terminology is, but it masks uncertainty. I.e. if a subject does 2 trials and gets half of them right, is really a very different result that if a subject does 50 trials and gets 25 of them right.

Comment: @Alex I don't think so. Even with sample size <- 100 I get the same errors

Comment: @BillConnelly That is not a valid reason to avoid binomial GLMs, as they take that into account. Maybe you can edit your question to be a bit more focused on the problem you're trying to model instead of the proposed solution, to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). If angle is in $[0,90]$, that would seem to suggest it is an actual angle... of what?

Comment: @FransRodenburg I have added some more details above. I'm not sure what other details would be necessary, but I can assure you, what the angle represents is not one of them.

Comment: I'm trying to help you add the necessary details to the question so that I or someone else can write a good answer. I understand that you have thought about this experimental design a lot more than me, but by simply assuring me I don't need to know more, I don't suddenly understand the question better. "*What I'm trying to model is how angle alters the probability of the subject getting the answer correct.*" sounds to me like the outcome is correct/incorrect and angle is an explanatory variable. If that is the case, wouldn't it make more sense to model the problem as a binomial GLM?

Comment: "test that this function behaves" What behaves do you want to test?

Comment: @FransRodenburg I'm interested in binomial GLM, but everywhere I read (which is only a few places that aren't actually looking at logistic) are really just performing: glm(Y/N~X1+X2,family=binomial ...). If you know how to run a binomial regression that takes into account the number of trials, as well as the number of successes, I'm very interested to hear.

Re: angle. The subject is shown a set of lines of a particular angle. Then shown two sets of lines. The subject has to pick which one is matches the original. Only one does. The angle is the difference between the two sets of lines.

Comment: @user158565 In English, if one is said to behave, it means that ones behaviour is good, as in, fitting within expected norms.

Comment: It seems you are talking about English, instead of statistics or math. I am not interesting on English.

Comment: @BillConnelly If you use `glm(cbind(success, total) ~ ., family = "binomial")`, the model takes the number of trials into account. Since you have repeated measures (before/after), better would be `glmer(cbind(success, total) ~ . + (1 | ID), family = "binomial")` to account for dependence (using the package `lme4`).

Comment: @FransRodenburg No, I don't have repeated measures. Different subjects before and after. Isn't your approach essentially throwing out data? i.e.I know before hand that this data will have a sigmoidal shape, and the results of experiments with similar angles will have similar responses? i.e. what you've done is like a one way ANOVA, without assuming normality, yes?

Comment: I don't follow. No information is thrown away this way. There is no need to bin angles, if that is what you mean. Instead of an ANOVA type regression, you can estimate a linear effect of angle, or a linear effect of angle after some appropriate transformation (like arcsine square root).

Comment: @FransRodenburg If no information is thrown away, then how come you don't need to inform the model of the angle?

Comment: Ah, I see now what you mean. `y ~ ., data` means: regress `y` on all other columns found in `data`. I used it for brevity, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @FransRodenburg I think this is just going back to the original situation of fitting a classical logarithmic function to the data, and that function fits the data terribly because it is assymptotic with y = 0 when x -> -infinity, which this data doesn't. (post 1/2)

Comment: @FransRodenburg
`mdl.simp <- glm(cbind(success, total) ~ angle, family = "binomial", data=bob2)`
`predicted <- predict(mdl.simp, list(angle = angles), type="response")`
`plot(bob2$angle, bob2$success)`
`lines(angles, predicted*10) #because total = 10`

Shows a terrible fit.

Comment: I don't real;ly understand what your code is trying to plot. But the fact that the logistic regression is inappropriate  as x goes to neg infinity seems irrelevant, if you data stays between 0 and 90.  The problem seems more that the log odds is not a linear function of the angle.  so as has been suggested you try non linear transformations of the data or splines (eg ns(angle, df = 5) ).

Comment: I am very sad that this question was put on hold. I, like the original poster, am interested to know why the reweighted least squares algorithm implemented in R doesn't seem to like this custom link function.

Comment: @BillConnelly For your modelling problem, I suggest you use the usual logit link, however, in the regression, admit the term $\operatorname{logit}\frac{1}{2}$ as an offset along with the rest of the covariates. Your link function at $p = 0.5$ is incompatible with the data you have simulated (and maybe what you expect to see), since at $p = 0.5$, you will see some samples where the sample mean probability is less than 0.5. This definitely causes problems in the fitting stage. If you wish to use the given link function I think you are going to have to simulate data in a different way.